# AppEngine - Java - insert object from web interface

Tags: java, google-app-engine, object, web, insert

I can't get it working to insert an object from my web interface...

I have a formular and on ok click I start a java function...

My EndpointClass has follwing auto generated insert function

```
 @ApiMethod(name = "insertQuestion")
public Question insertQuestion(Question question)
{
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    try
    {
        if (containsQuestion(question))
        {
            throw new EntityExistsException("Object already exists");
        }
        mgr.persist(question);
    }
    finally
    {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return question;
}
```

and I have a simple Question class

```
 @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Key key;

private String question;

private String answerCorrect;
private String answerWrong1;
private String answerWrong2;
private String answerWrong3;

public Question(String question, String answerCorrect, String answerWrong1, String answerWrong2, String answerWrong3)
{
    this.question = question;
    this.answerCorrect = answerCorrect;
    this.answerWrong1 = answerWrong1;
    this.answerWrong2 = answerWrong2;
    this.answerWrong3 = answerWrong3;

}

// + all the getters and setters...
```

I tried to add it like the following from my web page:

```
var question = document.formQuestion.elements[0];
var answer = document.formQuestion.elements[1];
var answerWrong1 = document.formQuestion.elements[2];
var answerWrong2 = document.formQuestion.elements[3];
var answerWrong3 = document.formQuestion.elements[4];

var q2 = new Object();
q2.question = question;
q2.answerCorrect = answer;
q2.answerWrong1 = answerWrong1;
q2.answerWrong2 = answerWrong2;
q2.answerWrong3 = answerWrong3;
gapi.client.questionendpoint.insertQuestion({q2}).execute(handleMessageResponse);
//gapi.client.questionendpoint.insertQuestion(q2).execute(handleMessageResponse);
//gapi.client.questionendpoint.insertQuestion({"question": q2}).execute(handleMessageResponse);
```

but that (and all other things I tried) are not working...

Can somebody show me how to do that correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You should not have curly brackets around the object "q2". Where do you add the answers to the object q2? q2 must have the same attributes as the object you expect in the endpoint.
Also;
Have you imported the Javascript client library, otherwise the gapi will not work.
Also have you tried to discover the API through the https://.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis, which will give the urls for the rest endpoints. 
An other very good tool is the api explorer, which you can use both against localhost (debug) and the deployed version: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?base=https://your_base_url/_ah/api#p/

Hope this helps

Comment: ok, I edited my post and added the lines I forgot to add, the lines that describe how q2 is initialised... I tried it now without the brackets around the q2, but that alone didn't work yet... I even tried using `gapi.client.question q2 = new gapi.client.question(question, answer, answerWrong1, answerWrong2, answerWrong3);` but that as well didn't work... gapi is working so far, I can list everything inn tables and that is working well... Maybe you have another hint? I will have a look into the api explorer... maybe that helps me...

Comment: I can ses a few differences. I have also given the endpoint a path, not sure if it means anything. Is it working locally on you own machine? Try to debug the endpoint class and check what kind of object it is receiving. Also try with var req = gapi.clientquestionendpoint.insertQuestion(q2).execute(handleMessageResponse); And then a new line with a call back

Comment: Also try with var req = gapi.clientquestionendpoint.insertQuestion(q2).execute(handleMessageResponse); And then a new line with a call back lile req.execute( function( data ){}); and check if the data object has anything in it.

Comment: tried even `req = gapi.client.questionendpoint.insertQuestion(q).execute(function( data ){alert(data);});alert(req);` and all I can see is that data and req are not defined... actually, I can run it locally but didn't manage to be able get it running, locally my list functions don't finish... Although I started the AppEngine in eclipse...

Comment: Sorry, what i ment was: var req = gapi.client.questionendpoint.insertQuestion(q) and then req.execute( function( data ){ alert( data.length) }); Check if this runs at all and what is in the data object (debug the script in the chrome developer tool)

Comment: I appreciate your help very much... I tried now `var req = gapi.client.questionendpoint.insertQuestion(q);
 alert("Req: " + req);
 alert("Req.question: " + req.question);
 req.execute( function( data ){ alert("Data.lenght: " + data.length) });` and `req.question`is undefined... as the `insertQuestion` method returns a question this should be defined, shouldn't it? but `req` is existing... I will have a look at the chrome developer tool at home... maybe that can help

Comment: Aha, do you load the gapi any where? Like this:  gapi.client.load('your_app_id', 'v1', function(){}, "https://your_app_id.appspot.com/_ah/api"); Otherwise gapi does not know where to send the request, etc. A very good tutorial is this one, which you can modify: http://bit.ly/159EwCK

Comment: yes, I'm doing this in the onload event... as I said,showing a list of all questions is no problem... so that means for me, the gapi is loaded correctly... I'm doing like that `gapi.client.load('questionendpoint', 'v1', function() {
      updateQuestionsTable();
    });`

Comment: thanks so much, I managed to do it with your help. The debugger for javascript helped me (chrome developer tool). So I found out, that my object for the function did not match the one that the function expected... Now I define my question like following: `var q = {};
 q['question'] = question;
 q['answer'] = answer;
 q['answerWrong1'] = answerWrong1;
 q['answerWrong2'] = answerWrong2;
 q['answerWrong3'] = answerWrong3;` and I insert the object with `var req = gapi.client.questionendpoint.insertQuestion(q);
 req.execute( function( data ){ alert("Data.lenght: " + data.length) });`

Comment: don't know if it's the changed code from the just posted reply, maybe it was just the wrong function footprint, because 'var question = document.formQuestion.elements[0];' at this point the main problem was... I did not get the value, so I hat a html element instead of a string... so `var question = document.formQuestion.elements[0].value;` solved this problem